# How to get Bower Install to copy files to another directory before linking them in html file?

Tags: gruntjs, bower-install

In my gruntfile.js I am using bower install to create the necessary script tags in my index.html for all my js libraries. My grunt file entry looks like this:

```
   bowerInstall: {
      target: {
        src: ['wwwroot/index.html'],
        cwd: '',
        dependencies: true,
        devDependencies: true,
        exclude: [],
        fileTypes: {},
        ignorePath: '',
        overrides: {}
      }
    }
```

My index.html gets correctly updated from my index.html.tpl as seen here:

```
<head>
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wwwroot/app/styles/style.css" />
```

What I want to happen is to copy all js library files to a specific lib directory, and then link them from there. Can this be accomplished with bower install or is there another grunt plug-in I should be using? The bower-install plugin seems popular but I can't find much documentation for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use [grunt-bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower) along with grunt-bower-install. You can configure bower to install copy files to specific folders. It will look like this:

```
bower: {
  dev: {
    dest: 'lib/',
    js_dest: 'lib/js',
    css_dest: 'lib/styles'
  }
}
```

Then if you run the task:

```
grunt bower
```

You will have something like this in your `lib` folder:

```
  /js
    /package1
      package1_file1.js
      package1_file2.js
    /package2
      package2.js
  /styles
    /package1
      package1.css
    /package2
      package2.css
```

Comment: I am trying this, and the copy seems to work great, now I just need to get bower install to pull the components from here instead of the native bower_components folder. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you should change the directory in your `bower.json`

Comment: Exactly, if you add this to your `bower.json` `{ "directory": "lib" }` when you run grunt bowerInstall it will get from this folder

Comment: I haven't tested but I think you can also add the `directory` to your bowerInstall grunt config like `bowerInstall: { ..., directory: 'lib' }`

Comment: I tried adding the lib path to the bower.json file, and that doesn't seem to work, neither does adding the directory to the bowerInstall config in my grunt file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I marked this answer as it got me to where I need to be. I am using include source to link the files from lib now instead of bower install.

Comment: I can't get js_dest, or css_dest to work. Everything ends up in the dest directory. Any pointers for debugging? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a `.bowerrc` file next to your `bower.json`. If the file is already in there change its content from:

```
{
    "directory": "bower_components"
}
```

to

```
{
    "directory": "you/new/lib/path"
}
```

Re-install your Bower components:

```
bower install
```

Then call the Grunt task:

```
grunt bowerInstall
```

Comment: This would require having my bower_components folder under my lib folder though, wouldn't it?